# Drop down - Displaying the data as per user selection

Tags: php, cakephp, drop-down-menu, cakephp-2.0

I have a bulletin board that displays data from the database. I want to display them in different categories  and so I added a category column in my database ( with randomly assigned values category1, category2, category3)

If the user selects a category from a drop-down (which has distinct values from category column), the data corresponding to that category will be displayed.
example.:  if the user selects category1 from drop-down, the page should display the data corresponding to category1, if he selects category2.. etc.

My drop-down in view

```
<?php echo $this->Form->input('cat', array('type'=>'select', 'options'=>$data, 'label'=>false, 'empty'=>'CATEGORY')); ?>
```

and the value displayed as follows

```
<?php echo $post['Post']['category']; ?>
```

Post is my Model and category is the column name.

I am a beginner in cakePHP and right now clueless on how to proceed, any help will be appreciated.

I think I should be using following code

```
$selected_value = $this->request->data('Post.cat');
```

(Post being the Form )and then

```
if ($selected_value == category1){...}
```

but $selected_value is getting NULL, also I am still trying to figure out, how to extract and display, particular data.

May be by using such condition ?

```
 $post['Post']['category'] == 'category1';
```

Anyway, still working on it and any help will be appreciated, Thank you!

Comment: *"May be by using such condition ?

 $post['Post']['category'] == 'category1';"* - you need to remove one of the equal signs if you'd want to use that. `$post['Post']['category'] = 'category1';`

Comment: I'm i bit confused about your question... Let me try to reconstruct it and you can correct me if i'm wrong: You have a form with one dropdown field. After the user submits the form, the categorie value is transmitted to your controller.  Based on the categorie value you want to get your `post Model` data... correct?

Comment: almost ... but I want the form to be submitted once he selects a value from drop down (kind of like javascript onchange)...

also , I have a form with drop down field and some data ( the bulletin board), so if the user selects category1 from the drop down field  (which is on the same bulletin board) the data which corresponds to category1 should be displayed.

P.S: I got a little closer to my result by studying about associations, still quite not there yet